# How to animate tableView reload on UISegmentedControl click as pushviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, uiviewanimation

I have relod the UITableview data on segment click as show in image below:

[image]

Now I want to animate tableView reload on UISegmentedControl click same as  `navigationController pushViewController` but there appears transition screen between the movement of table view

I have try to use following but was unable to get totally what i wants to
    -(void)SwipeGestureRecognize{

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
    swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
    swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];



}
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    //past Order

    [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame,   [Util window_width],0);

    }];

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0-[Util window_width], [Util window_height]);

    [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame,   [Util window_width],0);
    }];



    segmetControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    [self action:Nil];

}

-(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Current Order

    [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame,   [Util window_width],0);

    }];

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0-[Util window_width], [Util window_height]);

    [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame,   [Util window_width],0);
     }];


    segmetControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self action:Nil];
}
```

Comment: How many table view are you using?

Comment: single tableview i just reload the data just that

Comment: See the animation used in push view controller is like moving from left to right. In your case it is not. You have to set the frame accordingly and then you can see the animation.

Answer (score 2):

I would Suggest you to use a `UICollectionView` on the top  and Make Custom Cells With view's width Containing `UITableView`
and when the segment control valueChange:  Scroll to particular Cell you want to use.
Also Remember to Making

```
CollectionView PagingEnabled = YES
```

Comment: I prefer to use table view rather then collection view with slight animations

Comment: Yeah That can work to..In my case the segment was dynamic. like question answer round although you can use table view with horizontal scrolling or collectionview

Comment: any way thanks for suggestion . can u give me some ideas about my current situations

Comment: In your case you are using same UITableView .try to use 2 diffrent table view and Transit .This might be the case here

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code.

```
-(void)swipeleft
{
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height)
        [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);
        }];
}

 -(void)swiperight{
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);

        [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);

        }];
    }
```

Comment: I would try your code and reply you about the output

Comment: Thanks I have achieve what i want but there is some problem that transition white view in between them

Comment: I have upvoted for your efforts and hope same from u

Comment: hey can u help me out

Comment: hey can u help me out please

Comment: do u have any ideas ab this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049551/accessing-custom-cell-attributes-outside-of-cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Please make a sample project which was not working and upload to github. It will be more easy to solve your problem. Thanks.